# How to query documents which are arrays

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm a novice Couchbase user and I have a bucket which I've created that contains documents which are actually arrays in the form of:

```
{
    "key": [
        {
            "data1": "somedata1"
        },
        {
            "data2": "somedata2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query these documents via N1QL statements and have yet to find a solution to how to do this properly. More specifically, I would like to select fields inside each sub-document that is in an array of a certain key. For example, I would like to access: `key.[1].data2` or `key.[0].data1`

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase has some reserved keywords that need to be escaped.  In this case, `key` needs to be escaped.  For example, if you're querying against `my_bucket`, then

```
SELECT my_bucket.`key`[0].data1 FROM my_bucket;
```

should return `somedata1`